# Can't remove the EventListener by removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove the EventListener but the error messages shown as follows in Chrome debug mode:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of
>   undefined

I don't know what the problem is and the codes shown as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
var vote = null;
function init() {
    vote = document.querySelectorAll("div>span>img");


    for (var index = 0; index < vote.length; index++) {
        //document.getElementById(("img" + index)).innerHTML = '<img   src="../images/voteoff.png" />';
        event.stopPropagation();
        vote[index].setAttribute("src", "../images/voteoff.png");
        vote[index].setAttribute("id", index);




        vote[index].addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver, false);
        vote[index].addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut, false);
        vote[index].addEventListener("click", MouseOnclickVote, false);
        //vote[index].onmouseover = function () { MouseOverVote(this.id);}
        //vote[index].onmouseout = MouseOutVote;
        event.stopPropagation();
        //vote[index].onclick = function () { MouseOnclickVote(this.id); }

    }
```

function MouseOnclickVote() {

```
        length = this.id;
        console.debug(length);
        for (var index = 0; index <= length ;  index++) {
            console.debug(index);
            console.debug(vote[index]);
            vote[index].removeEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOver);
            vote[index].removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOut);

        }


    }
}
var handleMouseOver = function MouseOverVote() {


    length = this.id;



    for (var index = 0; index <= length ; index++) {

        vote[index].setAttribute("src", "../images/voteok.png");
        vote[index].parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.textContent = "你按了" + (index + 1) + "個讚";
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

var handleMouseOut = function MouseOutVote() {

    for (var index = 0; index < vote.length ; index++) {
        vote[index].setAttribute("src", "../images/voteoff.png");
        vote[index].parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.textContent = "";
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: `vote[i]` should probably be `vote[index]`

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: event is not defined`.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You're trying to reference an object that actually doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your vote[i] should be vote[index]

but you can also check first to see if remove event listener is a function

```
if(typeof vote[index].removeEventListener === "function") {
  // you can remove it 
} else { // you can't remove it, it doesn't have a listener
}
```

Comment: The problem is just a typo. The OP is referencing a variable `i` when actually it should be `index` in one of the loops.

Comment: yeah I edited my answer.. looks like he needs to learn how to use the console with break points